Different behaviour of UIKit
Recently I have encountered a crash about UIGraphicsBeginImageContext.
The fact is that if you build the project with XCode15 and run the app on iOS17, it will crash. But if you build the project with XCode14 or earlier version, it will not crash on iOS17.
I don't understand how the difference is caused since UIKit is a system dynamic library. UIKit is built-in in iPhone, it's already there and it's not an output of the XCode build process. The code inside UIKit should behave consistently on one specific iPhone, regardless of which XCode builds the app.
If anyone can explain the cause of the difference, I'm all your ears.
